# Send commands from OSX to windows?

Tags: macos, command-line, remote-access

I would like a way for OSX machines to be able to send a command to a windows pc with a desktop shortcut. For example:

```
CALL C:\example.bat
```

I have managed this sending the command from a windows machine, but I would like the same with OSX.